# Any Linux NTFS drivers which can create symlinks that work in Windows?

Tags: linux, windows, ntfs, symbolic-link

I'm dual-booting Windows 10 and Ubuntu 18.04 and am using NTFS-3G to mount my NTFS drives in Ubuntu. My fstab mount options are `defaults,relatime,inherit,hide_dot_files,big_writes,dmask=002,fmask=002,uid=1000,gid=1000`.

Is there a mount option or recommended driver to create Windows compatible symlinks on an NTFS filesystem via Linux? On the Windows side of things, my user has the `Create symbolic links` permission, links created via WSL work fine in both Windows and Linux. These are "real" symbolic links and not just a copy of the file. However, links created via Linux do not work in Windows (with the exception of Git/Bash for Windows which seems to have special handling).

I've spent a few hours trying to find a solution but both kernel and fuse FS drivers are beyond me. It appears that NTFS-3G does not set the `system.ntfs_reparse_data` attribute for links that it creates. I'm not sure if anything else is required to indicate to Windows that the file is a symlink, possibly setting the system attribute if it's not already.

Currently I'm running a script periodically in Windows which recurses an entire directory to look for anything that [looks like](https://github.com/andrewmackrodt/dokarr/blob/9df704c/machine/share/convert-symlinks.sh#L112) a Linux symlink and then recreates it in Windows so that it works in both OS'. This takes ~10 minutes on an SSD with about 100,000 files in the directory.

Comment: How about using WINE.

Comment: I'm not sure WINE would act any differently but isn't applicable to my use case (sharing a Plex docker container which uses symlinks for artwork).